# Слова, однокоренные ноябрю

Tags: этимология, лексика, однокоренные-слова, заимствования

Какие в русском языке есть слова, исторически или даже синхронически однокоренные названию этого осеннего месяца?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только имена Нонна и Ноябрина. Ноннами называли девятого ребёнка в семье. Ноябрины - дни рождения в ноябре.

Некоторые учёные усматривают историческое родство слов ноябрь - новый - девять-девяносто.

Вот у Фасмера: **Девять**. Признается связь между и.-е. *nevɨ̥̄ и *nevos «новый» (см. но́вый), потому что с девяти начинается новый отрезок счета, в то время как и.-е. *ok̂tōu «восемь» своей формой двойств. числа свидетельствует о древнем четверичном счете; см. Вальде — Гофм. 2, 180; Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 144; Преобр. 1, 177.

У Успенского читаем: "Его история — самая сложная из всех.
Во многих близких к нашему языках число «9» обычно означалось словами, связанными со словом, значащим «новый». В немецком языке «9» — «нойн», «новый» — «ной»; по-латыни «9» — «но́вем», «новый» — «но́вус». Ученые думают, что древние, ведя счет четверками, считали «9» новым, первым в 3-й четверке числом. Судя по этому, у славян оно должно было бы прозвучать как «но́вять». Но слишком сильным оказалось влияние следующего за ним числа «10»; по сходству с ним возникла неправильная форма «девять»".

https://uspensky.lexicography.online/%D0%B4/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Так что искать именно исторически однокоренное слово к ноябрю в русском языке нет смысла. Ноябрь - девятый месяц, а само слово девять образовано неверно, поэтому слова девять и ноябрь не воспринимаются однокоренными, а источник у них один. Если проследить путь заимствования, нужно отметить, что ноябрь заимствовано из старославянского,, а ст.-слав. позаимствовал его из греческого noembris,-em-дало носовой юс-малый,изменившийся потом в я, потом сократилось окончание, получилось ноябрь

Answer (score 1):

1. Ноябрьский, по-ноябрьски.
2. Ноябрёнок, ноябрята, ноябрятки, ноябрятский (аналогия с октябрёнок, октябрята, октябрятки, октябрятский).
3. Имена собственные: г. Ноябрьск; Ноябрьский квартал (с. Приволжье); Ноябрьская улица (г. Сочи, Лазаревский р-н, с. Солохаул).
   Ноябрина Викторовна Мордюкова.
4. *Станет воздух октябрёвным,

   Станут травы хрустовистей.

   [Ноябристый](https://stihi.ru/2009/11/10/5233) иней дрёмный

   Поползёт по склизким листьям.*

*Проснулось [ноябрёво](https://proza.ru/2012/11/01/741) небо:

Там облака, а солнце здесь,

Парит ворона с коркой хлеба,

Улёгся ветер, сбросив спесь...*

*Нежный снег, синий снег,

[Ноябрёвый](http://balmontoved.ru/almanah-solnechnaja-prjazha/vypusk-3/mne-vsegda-zhelanna-shuja/54-aleksej-dubrovin-stihi.html).

Ты ж опять на весь свет

Хмуришь брови.*

5. Ноябрёвский, ноябрёво-промозглая, ноябрелло, ноябрьнье, ноябрьшный, ноябряшка.

Comment: Римма, спасибо! Я ищу еще не сразу заметное, а оно как-то всё не находится. Вот, например, декабрь — декада. Родство чисто этимологическое. Если что-то вспомните, буду благодарен!

Comment: Ноябризм - течение финского экспрессионизма, связанное с «Ноябрьской группой» начала 20 века. Ноябристы - наименование, часто даваемое разным политическим группам.